# How to sort a text file by lines?

Tags: c, arrays, sorting

I would like to know a simple way to sort a text file by lines.
I have 2 files:

file1:

```
asazxz
dsa dsasd 
dsds tut
pewoq
```

file2:

```
uiosda dsds
poisss
```

my current code is:

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<stdlib.h>
#include<string.h>

int main(int argc, char *argv[]){

int nrf1=0;
int nrf2=0;

FILE *f1=NULL;
FILE *f2=NULL;
FILE *fe=NULL;
f1=fopen(argv[1],"r");
f2=fopen(argv[2],"r");
fe=fopen(argv[3],"w");

if (f1==NULL || f2==NULL || fe==NULL){
printf("couldn't open a file \n");
return 1;
}
char p;

while (1){
p=fgetc(f1);
if(p==EOF) break;
nrf1++;
    }

    while(1){
    p=fgetc(f2);
    if(p==EOF) break;
    nrf2++;
}

rewind(f1);
rewind(f2);

while ( (p = fgetc(f1))!= EOF )
        fputc(p,fe);

while ( (p = fgetc(f2))!= EOF )
        fputc(p,fe);

//if(nrf1>nrf2){
//printf("%s %d \n",argv[1],\nrf1);
//while( (p=fgetc(f1))!=EOF )
//
//}
//else{
//printf("%s %d \n",argv[2],nrf2);
//while( (p=fgetc(f2))!=EOF )
//
//}

rewind(fe);


fclose(f1);
fclose(f2);
fclose(fe);
return 0;
}
```

I merged file1 and file2 in a file3

I have some ideas of how i can sort file 3 by lines but i dont really know how to make them happen.

One is going through the longer text out of the two, find a \n and all the text up until the \n to be put in an array and the sort the array and then put each element of the sorted array on a line form file3.

The other is going through file3 and try somehow to switch the lines alphabitically, like bubblesort.

**edit:managed to do it , just needed some direction, thanks everyone**

Comment: Can you use the linux sort command?

Comment: Given that a large chunk of "The Art of Computer Programming Volume 3" is devoted to answering this field, I think this is poster child "too broad" question.

Comment: What's the purpose of that first loop?

Comment: For tiny files like this, I'd read each line into a malloc'ed array (doubling the size of the array with realloc every time the line was too long), and store the lines in an array (also malloced and realloced).  Then sort the lines and write out.

Comment: @MartinBonner Given that I can think of about half a dozen reasonable solutions without having read that particular book, I have to agree with you.

Comment: wanted to see which one of the text files has more characters

Comment: @Mad Physicist.  It gets more interesting when the files are so large that they have to be stored on tape.  Bubble sort *can* then become a reasonable approach.

Comment: @MartinBonner I've written an approach before that sorts multiple small chunks in place, then merges them together in pairs. Remarkably low memory overhead and the speed was good enough for my purpose at the time.

Answer (score 2):

As a verbal procedure, you can do:

1. Allocate an array of pointers to chars
2. Read all lines of the file. Allocate a new string for each line and put in the array
3. If the array is too small, then use `realloc` to make it larger. Read about `realloc` to avoid common errors.
4. Once the file has been read, use your own bubble sort or the library's `qsort` to sort the array. Read about `qsort`.
5. Once sorted, re-write `file3` from the array.

Coding this is a nice excercise that I leave to you.

Answer (score 1):

Easy way: read the text files into one array (first line of second file following last line of first file (hint: `fgets`), sort the array (hint: `qsort`), and output.

Answer (score 1):

If you really want to do it in C, you may want to read the whole file using the `getline (3)` function, and put the result in a linked list in case you do not know the number of lines of the file.

Once done, you could simply use `strcmp (3)` with the sorting algorithm of your choice (bubble sort, insertion sort, etc...).

You'd then be able to re-open the file for writing and insert your sorted linked list.

---

**Edit**:

As asked in the comments by @alk, I think it'd be better for your programs to use linked lists instead of regular array in case you do not know the size of your file.

**Pro**:
You do not know the size of your file, using an array would force you to use `realloc (3)` which would be costly in resources over time as the realloc function actually creates a new pointer, copy the whole content of the date pointed by your old pointer, and free the old pointer. If the file is relatively short, it shouldn't be a problem, but when you'll begin to have large files, it could potentially be an issue regarding the performances.

**Con**:
Linked list effectively complexifies your work. A way around that would be to create your very own general liked list lib, and use it in the projects you need so you only have to do it once.

Comment: Doesn't a linked list complicate this a bit? If proposing such kind of advanced data structure explaining its pros (and cons?) might be worth it.

Comment: @alk Very right, just added the explanations to help OP to make his choice.